I am trying to convert a Flutter widget to an image. But getting some exception while release build creation
Error while building > flutter build apk:
E/flutter ( 1555): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Local 'result' has not been initialized.
E/flutter ( 1555): #0 LateError._throwLocalNotInitialized (dart:_internal-patch/internal_patch.dart:190) E/flutter ( 1555): #1 RenderObject.debugNeedsPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart) E/flutter ( 1555): #2 _HomeScreenState._capturePng (package:geeta_gyandhara/screens/home/home_screen.dart:48) E/flutter ( 1555): #3 _HomeScreenState.buildShlokaCard.<anonymous closure> (package:geeta_gyandhara/screens/home/home_screen.dart:169) E/flutter ( 1555): #4 _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1171)
E/flutter ( 1555): #5 GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:344) E/flutter ( 1555): #6 TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:652)
E/flutter ( 1555): #7 BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:309) E/flutter ( 1555): #8 BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:279) E/flutter ( 1555): #9 GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:167) E/flutter ( 1555): #10 GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:499) E/flutter ( 1555): #11 GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:475)
E/flutter ( 1555): #12 RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:425) E/flutter ( 1555): #13 GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:420) E/flutter ( 1555): #14 GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:383)
E/flutter ( 1555): #15 GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:330) E/flutter ( 1555): #16 GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:299) E/flutter ( 1555): #17 _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:328) E/flutter ( 1555): #18 PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:442) E/flutter ( 1555): #19 _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:262) E/flutter ( 1555):

Code:
This code runs properly in debug mode, but it shows an exception when I use flutter build apk

   Future<Uint8List> _capturePng(GlobalKey key) async {
     RenderRepaintBoundary? boundary =
        key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary?;
     if (boundary == null) {
       print("Boundary is not available.");
       return Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 20), () => _capturePng(key));
     }


   if (boundary.debugNeedsPaint) {
      print("Waiting for boundary to be painted.");
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 20));
      return _capturePng(key); // Recursively retry capturing
    }


       ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
    ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    if (byteData == null) {
      throw 'Error converting image to ByteData';
    }
    return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    
    }


  Widget buildShlokaCard(
      String hindiText, String englishText, String sanskritText, img,GlobalKey key) {
    return  RepaintBoundary(
      key: key,
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width.w,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colorWhite,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.r),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.w),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0.w),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextWidget(
                  text: hindiText,
                  color: Colors.black, // Adjust color as needed
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                heightBox(10.h),
                TextWidget(
                  text: englishText,
                  color: Colors.black, // Adjust color as needed
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                heightBox(10.h),
                TextWidget(
                  text: sanskritText,
                  color: Colors.black, // Adjust color as needed
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ],
            ),
        
           
      
           Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
             child: IconButton(onPressed: (){
              
                       _capturePng(key).then((imageBytes) {
                  if (imageBytes != null) {
                    // Handle captured image bytes here (e.g., save/share/etc.)
                  _shareImage(imageBytes);
                    
                  } else {
                    print('Error capturing image');
                  }
                });
             }, icon: const Icon(Icons.share),),
           )
        
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

     void _shareImage(Uint8List imageBytes) async {
  try {
    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final file = await File('${tempDir.path}/shloka_image.png').create();
    await file.writeAsBytes(imageBytes);

    // Create an XFile instance from the file path
    final xFile = XFile(file.path);

    // Share the file
    await Share.shareXFiles([xFile], text: 'Check out this shloka from Bhagavad Gita!');
  } catch (e) {
    
    print('Error sharing image: $e');
  }
}


found solution ? if yes ! can you post it here. Thanks
